# Angular Dynamic Form Example With Multiple Validators

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

The official Angular docs have a [dynamic form tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) containing a story for dynamic forms. A service is used to create the FormGroup object like so:

```
    toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
    let group: any = {};

    questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
                                              : new FormControl(question.value || '');
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
```

How can I add more than one validator function to each FormControl object? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
questions.forEach(question => {
      group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)])
                                              : new FormControl(question.value || '');
    });
```

I've also tried `Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)])` which doesn't work as expected either. The only validator that seems to be applied is the 'required' validator. Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4YO4qvrt4AJdweWYHoTA?p=preview) demonstrating the behavior. The code mentioned above is contained in the question-control.service.ts file.

The expected outcome i'm trying to achieve is to have the maxLength validator also applied to the FirstName control.

Comment: @Vega The code is directly from the angular.io site. Only modifications that were made was adding an array of validators to the second param of the FormControl constructor

Comment: the validator works in your plunkr... What are you expecting as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validations are actually in place, but currently you just have a generic check if the field is not valid or not:

```
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div>
```

That will of course display this message if the field is not valid.

The quick solution is to check which error field has:

```
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="form.controls[question.key].hasError('required')">
   {{question.label}} is required
</div>
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="form.controls[question.key].hasError('maxlength')">
   {{question.label}} is too long
</div>
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/RQRQiJfQbnOHEPuS0jji?p=preview

But since your form is dynamic, I guess you also want a validation that is as dynamic as possible. For that I suggest you take a look at this sample from the **[official docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-forms-with-validation-in-code)** which are using an object `formErrors` and `validationMessages` with all validation messages stored, and then using these together with this method whenever there are changes in the form:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
  if (!this.heroForm) { return; }
  const form = this.heroForm;

  for (const field in this.formErrors) {
    // clear previous error message (if any)
    this.formErrors[field] = '';
    const control = form.get(field);

    if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
      for (const key in control.errors) {
        this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + ' ';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Validation doesn't appear to be in place, because form is valid on the first character input

Comment: I don't know... here it at least shows form is not valid if the name is too long: https://plnkr.co/edit/n5Y6Z0UCwjSd3ZfRfvvK?p=preview

Comment: You had validator for **maxlength** not **minlength**, is that what's confusing?

Comment: Consequence of staring at screen to long. Your right. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happens to all of us ;) Glad I could help, have a nice weekend Mike, and happy coding, but remember to rest your eyes and brain for a while in between :P

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is place the necessary validations for each question in an array, I did it this way:

```
toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
    const group: any = {};
    let validaciones = [];
    questions.forEach(question => {
      if (question.required) {
        validaciones.push(Validators.required);
      }
      // Validación para solo números
      if (question.number) {
        validaciones.push(Validators.pattern(/^([0-9])*$/));
      }

      group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '', validaciones);
      validaciones = [];

    });
```

I leave my repository on GitHub if you want to take a look
https://github.com/aleRozo/formulariosDinamicos/